# Excerpt "Read more>>" pointing to current URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page template set up to pull category post onto a "page"
I've set up a function for the excerpt to display.  "Read More>>" is present, however, the post id is not pulling in the permalink for the individual posts.  The excerpt after each post links to this same page I created.

functions.php-->

```
function excerpt($num) {
 $limit = $num+1;
 $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
 array_pop($excerpt);
 $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt). ' <a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="more-link" title="Read More">Read More >></a>';
echo $excerpt;
}

function excerpt_length($length) {
  return 40;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'excerpt_length');
```

content.php-->

```
<div class="entry-content">
<?php if ( is_category() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_home() ) {
        the_excerpt();
    } else {
        the_excerpt();
    } ?>
</div>
```

-------Another function I've been testing with similar results, which includes global $post.

```
 function themprefix_excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
   global $post;
 return $output . ' <a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="more-link" title="Read More">Read More >></a>';
}
 add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'themprefix_excerpt_read_more_link' );
```

Custom page template -->

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
   <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
    <div id="main-left" class="span8">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
                $catPost = get_posts('cat=225&posts_per_page=3');
                foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
            ?>

        <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div><!-- #main-left -->       
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div><!-- #main -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `global $post` in the beginning of your `excerpt()` function.

Comment: its usually preferable to parse the var in to the function rather than make it global `function excerpt($num,$post)`

Comment: You are correct, but that depends on how you use the function, and what control you have over its parameters. Overall, if you don't have control over parameters, and you are using the main query, the easiest way is to globalize the $post variable.

Comment: I've been unable to produce results using either of the suggestions

Comment: Can you please post some more code? Where and how exactly are you using the excerpt() function?

Comment: I still don't see where the excerpt() function is called.

Comment: In the content.php (child theme): else { the_excerpt();}   Switched out from the_content().  My knowledge is not vast, forgive my lack thereof.  The three files and the code above are the areas I'm modifying for this process.  This permalink issue is the only thing keeping me from moving forward.  I appreciate your efforts, Marin.